# Floating Action Button appears over Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design, floating-action-button

So I am using https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer for my navigation drawer and https://gist.github.com/Jogan/9def6110edf3247825c9 as my FAB implementation. When I open the navigation drawer, it does not cover the FAB, and the button appears on top of it. I would like to avoid hiding the button and showing it on drawer open/close as that is rather distracting. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit:
I am adding the FAB programmatically doing the following:

```
fabButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
            .withDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_edit))
            .withButtonColor(0xFF2196F3)
            .withGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.END)
            .withMargins(0, 0, 16, 16)
            .create();
```

Changing that declaration to the fragment does not fix it. The Nav Bar implementation I linked above requires the activity to extend from a MaterialNavigationDrawer class, which may draw the Nav Drawer first, leaving the button to always be last. Is there any way to programmatically force the ordering of the elements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You see FAB when the navigation drawer is open because this FAB implementation adds FAB to the content view (`android.R.id.content`). Depending on the navigation drawer implementation they seem to be on same level in the view hierarchy.

If you don't want to switch to different FAB implementation. Use `onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float offset)` and change FAB alpha as you open the drawer. Also you could toggle its visibility inside `onDrawerClose()` or `onDrawerOpen()` methods too.

**Edit:**

```
@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float offset){
   fabButton.setAlpha(offset);
}
```

Comment: I have tried changing the visibility and it works, but the animation draws the attention away from the drawer and towards the button. Could you please elaborate on alpha, I am not very familiar with it.

Comment: Well, you have two more options: modify the original implementation to add FAB to your fragment layout or hide fab as soon as nav drawer is peeking. See my edit on your question about changing alpha.

Comment: The implementation helps with the animation. I would ideally like to have the nav drawer overlay the button. The issue I am having is that the Nav Drawer implementation forces me to not have an onCreate method, so I can't set a content view. Instead, it launches the fragment fixed to the first section in the drawer, so the fragment's layout is not available at that point. Is there any way to change the order in the content view?

Comment: Actually this implementation works well. One change though - it needs to be setAlpha(1-offset) as the button needs to be gone when the drawer is open.

Comment: This solution works great, except that I used `1 - offset`. However, when my drawer was open and I rotated the device, the FAB would not come back...

So I store the FAB alpha value as an instance variable in MainActivity, and save/restore it in the Bundle via onCreate( ) / onSaveInstanceState( ). This fixed the orientation change use case.

Comment: Solution is good, but It is inverted. @Andy H solution worked completely.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a neat solution that doesn't involve alpha in it or toggling the button when the drawer's opened or closed (which makes it look like a delay). Programmatically, you can modify the button's end margin so that it transitions out of the activity's window while the drawer's offset changes.

So first of all, outside the `onDrawerSlide` method, you must get the FAB's layout parameters with the following code (depending on the layout the button's in, in my case, it's a `FrameLayout`):

```
final FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
```

Understand that I'm doing this based on a simple mathematical linear equation: y = mx + n, while 'y' is the margin, 'm' is the slope (you can modify it), 'x' is the `slideOffset` and 'n' is the default/original margin (16dp). This is how you assign the default margin and the slope to variables as pixels while respecting the abundance of display densities:

```
int density = (int) Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
final int defaultMargin = 16 * density;
final int slope = -100 * density;
```

Then, inside `onDrawerSlide`, do the following:

```
params.setMarginEnd((int) (slope * slideOffset + defaultMargin));
fab.setLayoutParams(params);
```

If this doesn't work for you, try to set the button's `marginEnd` when building it, or set the margins of the layout's parameters like this (though you would have to check if `marginEnd` is right or left):

```
params.setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
```

I hope this helped. This is my first answer so I hope you won't have much complaints about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution which works for me.
Suppose you want to add FAB in yourlayout.xml.
Now create a framelayout in yourlayout.xml

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/myframelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Now in FloatingActionButton.java replace the method

```
public FloatingActionButton create() {
  ...
  ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
  root.addView(button, params);
  return button;
}
```

with

```
 public FloatingActionButton create(FrameLayout framelayout) {
  ...
  framelayout.addView(button, params);
  return button;
}
```

Now change the FAB declaration like this.

```
FrameLayout yourframelayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.myframelayout);

fabButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
        .withDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_edit))
        .withButtonColor(0xFF2196F3)
        .withGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.END)
        .withMargins(0, 0, 16, 16)
        .create(yourframelayout);
```

That's it!!

Answer (score 0):

I am updating **Nikola Despotoski** solution:

So you have to disable/hide the fab also after setting the alpha so if any time user taps at place where fab is shown then nothing would happen.

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {
   public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
               // Visible/Enable the FAB
   }

   public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
               // Hide/Disable the FAB
   }

   @Override
   public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                // invert the slideOffset value
                fab.setAlpha(1-slideOffset);
   }
};
```