# Material Design : how to set transparency for Android Floating Action Button

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design, floating-action-button

My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835992/floating-action-button-appears-over-navigation-drawer) one.

When I open the NavigationDrawer, the Floating Button is on the top of it but has to be below.

I try to do it like that :

```
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            Log.i(TAG , " inner onDrawerSlide");
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            fabButton.setAlpha(25);
            float alpha = 0.2f;
            AlphaAnimation alphaUp = new AlphaAnimation(alpha, alpha);
            alphaUp.setFillAfter(true);
            fabButton.startAnimation(alphaUp);
            syncState();
        }
```

and like that :

```
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                fabButton.setAlpha(255);
                syncState();
            }
```

Nothing worked for me. What can be the solution ?

My layout:

```
<mobapply.freightexchange.customviews.FragmentNavigationDrawer
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- The ActionBar -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
     />
```

FragmentNavigationDrawer is the custom `DrawerLayout`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Android [documentation for setAlpha(float alpha)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)) (since API 11):

> Sets the opacity of the view. This is a value from 0 to 1, where 0
>   means the view is completely transparent and 1 means the view is
>   completely opaque.

You're trying to set it to value `25` or `255` :)

Comment: Yeah, thank you, that helped. But the problem remains - even when I set 0.1f to the transparency, the but shows ABOVE the Navigation Drawer. Have to find better solution...

Comment: so the problem is with the positioning of your `Button` within your `DrawerLayout`, not with the alpha itself

Comment: yes, you're right - do you know how to do it programatically ?

Comment: Paste your layout xml

Answer (score 0):

This should hide it with a nice animation :

```
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                fabButton.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset);
                syncState();
            }
```

Or, you could slide it out of view :

```
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                fabButton.setTranslationX(slideOffset * 100);
                syncState();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

if the position of the fab is problem then make it draggable .
here is the code for that

```
private FloatingActionButton fab;
float dX;
float dY;
int lastAction;


fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnTouchListener(this);





@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
            dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
            lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            view.setY(event.getRawY() + dY);
            view.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);
            lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (lastAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Cart.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;

        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this line of code, but it may have an issue with the change in orientation of device.

```
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);

            fab.setAlpha(1-slideOffset);
        }
```